# How can I get a key count for StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have an azure redis cache. I've set it up so that I can do stringGet key setting based off [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysValues.md) example. It works pretty great.

However, I want to know if the cache is empty or not, or if there are any entries of (x) type of a C# object I have. I currently want to see if I can get a key count. I haven't found any solutions for this.

My only idea is to do a key scan that would search for every key (a get all) and then do a count. But that seems inefficient. Is there a more "meta" data style solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Per my understanding, you could leverage `IServer.Keys` to retrieve all keys with matching pattern as follows:

```
var endpoints=ConnectionMultiplexer.GetEndPoints();
var server = ConnectionMultiplexer.GetServer(endpoints.First());
var keys = server.Keys();
```

For more details about keys scanning, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan).

Comment: Here is the all documentation about [StackExchange.Redis] (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis), you could [see here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/).